# Trouble with a Poisson distribution problem

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> A manufacturer produces dinner plates and distributes them in boxes of varying sizes. The probability that a plate is not broken is $p$ (constant). How many plates at least should the manufacturer pack into a box so that the probability that at least $100$ plates in the box are intact is at least $80\%$? Use the Poisson distribution to approximate the probability.

As I understand it, I have to take a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=np$, where $n$ is the number of plates in a box, so that $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$ gives the approximate probability that $k$ of the $n$ plates are intact. Then, I have to find a minimum bound for $n$ such that $P(X\geq100)\geq0.8$ holds or, equivalently, such that $P(X<100)\leq0.2$ holds. The latter is equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^{99}\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}\leq0.2$ or
$$\sum_{k=0}^{99}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\leq0.2e^{\lambda}$$
From this point onward I am unsure of how to proceed. Specifically, how do I evaluate the left side of the expression and get a minimum bound for $\lambda$ (from there, I can just divide by $p$)? I tried interpreting the LHS as the $99$th Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ at $0$ evaluated at $\lambda$ and working with the error term, i.e. $r_{99}(\lambda)\geq 0.8e^\lambda$ must hold (then use the Lagrange representation and so on), but that seems to lead nowhere (even worse, it seems like circular reasoning).

Comment: For this problem to make sense, it would have to be the case that a plate not being broken is very rare.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Suppose it is so, how do I solve the inequality for $\lambda$ (and hence for $n$)?